# Virtual machine software

Tags: linux, fedora, virtual-machine

I am looking for a recommendation for virtualization software for IBM P5 series (ppc 64). I have Fedora 23 installed and just want to run 2-3 virtual machines but as I understood, given specific architecture of the computer, not every virtualization software will work.

Comment: And remember to upgrade to a current Fedora release before you do anything else.

Comment: What are you going to be running in the virtual machine? (the answer to this may determine the answer).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I intend to run simple client/server virtual machines, such as web server, mail server, file server, vulnerable Linux distribution as practice targets which will serve for experiment&learn purposes. All this will be in a local environment without WAN access.

Comment: If running same architecture services, then para-virtualisation will be better. E.g. Docker.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor What do you mean by "same architecture services"?

Comment: @Navi if you run Gnu/Linux then you can run services in docker, if they are also written for Linux and for the same processor. No virtualisation or emulation is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Start LPARs (you need AIX) and there install Linux. This is the best you can do about virtualization on PPC machine.
You can start by visiting [this page](https://www.ibm.com/servers/eserver/ess/index.wss) to download AIX.
And [this page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/POWER8/p8hdx/p8_create_virt_env.htm) for manual about LPARs

Answer (score 1):

KVM PR might work, if it's true, then the normal libvirt based virt tools (like virt-manager) will work as on any other Linux.

Comment: The performance penalty will be very big, as this is not PC x86 platform, but PPC. There is special reason IBM to provide own KVM version (for P8 serie)

Comment: Supposedly KVM is [supported natively](https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Processor_support) already.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, what I offer is to use embedded hypervisor and I have doubts KVM support it

Comment: @RomeoNinov It has supposedly worked for years. [Here is one tutorial from IBM](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/mhhaque/entry/How_to_install_Red_Hat_KVM_on_Power_System?lang=en_us) using RHEL7 as the hypervisor.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, this (from link) is linux only server and one of few which support PowerKVM. And most of Power servers support only PowerVM hypervisor